# Why is there no $-a\cdot t_0$ in the Taylor series?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Here is mine computation for uniform acceleration, i.e $v'(t) = \text{const}\ a$:

$$v(t) = v(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t} v'(t)dt = v(t_0) + a\cdot \Delta t$$ where $$\Delta t = t- t_0$$ and coordinate is therefore $$x(t) = x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t}x'(t)dt= x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t}v(t)dt = \\ x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t}(v(t_0) + a\cdot(t-t_0))dt = x(t_0) + v(t_0)\cdot \Delta t + a\int_{t_0}^{t}(t-t_0)dt =\\ x(t_0) + v(t_0)\cdot \Delta t + a(t^2/2 - t_0\cdot t)|_{t_0}^t =\\ x(t_0) + v(t_0)\cdot \Delta t + at^2/2 + a\cdot t_0 \cdot \Delta t = x_0 + (v_0 - a\cdot t_0)\Delta t + {a\Delta t\over 2}.$$ The term $-a\cdot t_0$ in the last equation bothers me. I do not remember that it was taught me in the school and I do not see it in the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have built an error in the second last equality. 
Hint: $\int (t-t_0) dt = \frac{(t-t_0)^2}{2}$.

Comment: Why is that? Integrals are distributed over summation, which means $\int (a+b)dt = \int a dt +\int b dt$

Comment: More precisely: $\int_{t_0}^t (t'-t_0) dt' = \int_{t_0}^t t' dt' -t_0(t-t_0)$. Now using $t^2-t_0^2=(t+t_0)(t-t_0)$ and simplification will give the result!